# How to have a lot of text in textView but only display some of it

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am sure that there is a lot of material on the web about the problem I am having, but since I am new to Android app development, I don't really know how to form the question (don't know the terms).

There are two buttons and a textView in my app:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="P1"
    android:id="@+id/history"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

When the buttons are pressed, a string is appended to textView (in a new line):

```
switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            counter -= 20;                
            stack.push(20);
            history.append("\r\n " + seznam.peek());
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            counter -= 1;                
            stack.push(1);
            history.append("\r\n " + seznam.peek());
            break;

        default: break;
    }
```

At the moment, when there is not enough space for new lines (100dp), only the old ones are visible, the new ones are not.

I would like, that the newest line is always visible, and that I had the option to see the old lines(via swipe).. (something like iframe without scrollbar)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a `ScrollView` actually.

Just set the

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your TextView in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

in your code.

It scrolls automatically without any issues.

Comment: Thanks for help! But it still doesn't automatically scroll down to the last line.. it stays at the top and you can scroll down.

Comment: OK, got it! You have to add 'gravity:"bottom"' to xml.

Comment: yes, by setting gravity of Textview to bottom and scrollbars vertical you can easily achieve it.